# Rails 2.3.11 Create Model for Form And Use ActiveRecord Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, activemodel

In Rails 3 you simply include ActiveRecord modules in order to add validations to any non-database backed model. I want to create a model for a form (e.g. ContactForm model) and include ActiveRecord valiations. But you cannot simply include the ActiveRecord modules in Rails 2.3.11. Is there any way to accomplish the same behavior as Rails 3 in Rails 2.3.11?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use the virtual class as a sort of validation proxy for more than one models, the following might help ( for 2.3.x, 3.x.x allows you to user ActiveModel as previously stated ):

```
class Registration
  attr_accessor :profile, :other_ar_model, :unencrypted_pass, :unencrypted_pass_confirmation, :new_email
  attr_accessor :errors

  def initialize(*args)
    # Create an Errors object, which is required by validations and to use some view methods.
    @errors = ActiveRecord::Errors.new(self)
  end

  def save
    profile.save
    other_ar_model.save
  end
  def save!
    profile.save!
    other_ar_model.save!
  end

  def new_record?
    false
  end

  def update_attribute
  end
  include ActiveRecord::Validations
  validates_format_of :new_email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  validates_presence_of :unencrypted_pass
  validates_confirmation_of :unencrypted_pass
end
```

this way you can include the Validations submodule, which will complain that `save` and `save!` methods are not available if you attempt to include it before defining them. Probably not the best solution, but it works.